# Issue for facebook comments iframe for vertical scrolling in IE browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I know facebook comments with iframe implementation is not supported. But I am using following code:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://yahoo.com"  style="border:none; overflow:scroll; width:400px; height:562px;"  scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
```

which works well in firefox but not in IE. I want fb comments in iframe only.